# Invisible double quotes in oracle column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have inserted one row in employee table in oracle database. Now I am trying to retrieve data from that employee table; but it gives me different value than what I have entered.

```
employee table (ID,Name,UniqueCode,Department)
insert into employee values('emp1','John','TEST05897','PAYROLL');

select ID,Name,UniqueCode,Department from employee where ID='emp1';
```

Above query returns me `"TEST05897"` for `UniqueCode` column; but I want it to be `TEST05897`. I wonder how I get double quotes in my data. I can apply `REPLACE()` method to remove those double quotes; but still I need to know how those double quotes are there in resultset.

Comment: Which database are you using?  You have tagged three of them.  My guess is that you are just looking at some output formatting from the console.  Perhaps the quotes are there just to remind you that it's varchar data.

Comment: Oracle database it is

Comment: The quotes are some sort of artifact.  They're either not really there, or they are there but can be ignored.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually I want to update this row, but update query fails as extra double quotes are there. so can't ignore them.

Comment: Show us the update query.

Comment: What tool or language are you using?

Comment: I think it's sql tool's problem. test with sql developer.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

Comment: I am using oracle developer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen update query is: update employee set Department='ACCOUNT' where UniqueCode='TEST05897'

Comment: @rajkhot can you share the error message. We couldnt replicate your issue.

Comment: Must be something with your tool, because Oracle will not add those quotes on its own. The only other thing I can imagine is a trigger that does that.

Comment: @VimalBhaskar its's not error so I can't share error message. it's just issue of invisible double quotes.

Comment: @rajKhot Screenshots of your working could also do. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using sql devloper and you might have modified something which we are not aware of  unless you provide us all the details. Moreover Please try running the commands in sqlplus (Command prompt) and see if that is going through. I have executed  everything in sqlplus and the same worked just fine. Please find the details below.

```
SQL> create table employee(id varchar2(10),name varchar2(20),uniquecode  varchar2(20),department varchar2(20))
  2  /

    Table created.

SQL> desc employee
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 VARCHAR2(10)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(20)
 UNIQUECODE                                         VARCHAR2(20)
 DEPARTMENT                                         VARCHAR2(20)

SQL> insert into employee values('emp1','John','TEST05897','PAYROLL');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from employee;

ID         NAME                 UNIQUECODE           DEPARTMENT
---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
emp1       John                 TEST05897            PAYROLL

SQL> update employee set Department='ACCOUNT' where UniqueCode='TEST05897';

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from employee;

ID         NAME                 UNIQUECODE           DEPARTMENT
---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
emp1       John                 TEST05897            ACCOUNT
```